# Is it possible to pass the authentication object (user credentials) from struts to spring framework web applications?

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, spring-security, struts

I have struts framework web application then want to embed my new spring framework.
But i want to just use the authentication info from struts application to my new spring application..

Any guidance on the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Did you think about using the request parameters to transfer a login-token? The other method could be a token in a cookie, that's how many shops transfer payment information: encrypted in a token

Comment: If i will use request, it should be encryted. Would you guide me on how to do it via request?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a database that both can talk with. In that database you would store a login token for a specific user Object. You generate the token via RijndaelAES or something comparable. Then you just link to the next site where you take the token as request parameter.

Be sure to limit the lifetime of the token to about 10 minutes or something like that. Define a place where you say "buildTokenForTransfer" and "destroyTokenAfterTransfer".